# Hyperlink in MS Word to an anchor on a web page

Tags: ms-word, anchor

I need to insert the following link in an MS Word document:

```
https://creabook.app/guide/topic.htm?#t=Part_1_Preliminaries%2FChapter%201%2C3%20Book%20cover%2FChapter_1%2C3_Book_cover.htm#subtitle
```

This redirects to the #subtitle anchor of the Web page.

When I save the link in the MS Word document, the format does not take into account the anchor [image: see screenshot]

I use MS Word 2019

Anyone have an idea how to insert links containing anchors?

Thx !

I tried to deactivate "update links on save" in File > Option > Advanced Options > General > Web Options > Files

No result.

Comment: You can add the bookmark, preceded by # at the end. Otherwise, you can click on the bookmark button on the right and pick a bookmark.

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word

Comment: Instead of going via the Hyperlink dialog, click where you want thel link to go in the document and paste your link, then click the spacebar or the Enter key. If you get the link you need, so much the better. If not, you'll need VBA code or some such to do it.

Comment: I fixed my issue. I pasted the link containing the anchor directly into the document. Then I right clicked "edit link" and just changed the text to display on the page. The solution was suggested to me on the Microsoft forum. Thank you for your ideas.